# Fast way to get the decimal value of certain bits from a bitset

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitset

I have a variable `mask` of type `std::bitset<8>` as

```
std::string bit_string = "00101100";
std::bitset<8> mask(bit_string);
```

Is there an efficient way to quickly mask out the corresponding (three) bits of another given `std::bitset<8> input` and **move all those masked out bits to the rightmost**? E.g., if `input` is `10100101`, then I would like to quickly get `00000101` which equals `5` in decimal. Then I can `vect[5]` to quickly index the 6th element of `vect` which is `std::vector<int>` of size 8.

Or rather, can I quickly get the decimal value of the masked out bits (with their relative positions retained)? Or I can't?

I guess in my case the advantage that can be taken is the `bitset<8> mask` I have. And I'm supposed to manipulate it somehow to do the work fast.

I see it like this (added by Spektre):

```
mask  00101100b 
input 10100101b
---------------
&     ??1?01??b
>>         101b
             5
```

Comment: Will the value of mask, `bit_string`, always be the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly"? Are you talking about beautiful/short code or lightning fast execution time?

Comment: I don't understand your example. If I mask `00101100 & 10100101` I get `00100100`, so no matter how I shift it, its not going to be `00000101`. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry it's not quite clear. So I'd like to pick bit 2, bit 3, and bit 5 (suppose the rightmost bit is bit 0) out of a given bit string and then move these three bits to the rightmost (with the original relative positions retained) for easy conversion to decimal. By quickly, I mean low complexity. E.g., if I'd like to count the number of set bits of a bit string, I can do it in O(m) where m is the number of set bits, instead of O(n) where n is the whole length. Is there an O(m) algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of providing information in comments. Make sure to correct your example as well as the other discussed points.

Comment: I edited your question (please check it if it is what you want) and also added answer

Comment: @WanxinGao If you're going to pick bits 2, 3 and 5, shouldn't your mask be `0b00101100`?

Comment: @legends2k the mask is `00101100b` and the input is `10100101b` also in OP text the only misleading thing is the first source where mask is not directly set to that bit_string instead it is done in 2 lines ... I was confused too but I think it is not wrong just confusing as the lines for input are missing... and usually the mask is second operand not first but that was our assumption ...

Comment: `_pext_u32` if you have it

Comment: Note that "decimal" is completely misleading. Your computer can't calculate `vect[5]`. Computers are binary, they calculate `vect[00000101]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: you can't avoid `O(n)` complexity with `n` being the number of mask bits if your mask is available as binary. However, if your mask is constant for multiple inputs, you can preprocess the mask into a series of `m` mask&shift transformations where `m` is less or equal to your number of value `1` mask bits. If you know the mask at compile time, you can even preconstruct the transformations and then you get your `O(m)`.

To apply this idea, you need to create a sub-mask for each group of `1` bits in your mask and combine it with a shift information. The shift information is constructed by counting the number of zeroes to the right of the current group.

Example:

```
mask = 00101100b
// first group of ones
submask1 = 00001100b
// number of zeroes to the right of the group
subshift1 = 2

submask2 = 00100000b
subshift2 = 3

// Apply:
input = 10100101b
transformed = (input & submask1) >> subshift1 // = 00000001b
transformed = (input & submask2) >> subshift2 // = 00000100b
    + transformed // = 00000101b
```

If you make the sub-transforms into an array, you can easily apply them in a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Your domain is small enough that you can brute-force this. Trivially, an `unsigned char LUT[256][256]` can store all possible outcomes in just 64 KB.

I understand that the mask has at most 3 bits, so you can restrict the lookup table size in that dimension to [224]. And since `f(input, mask) == f(input&mask, mask)` you can in fact reduce the LUT to `unsigned char[224][224]`.

A further size reduction is possible by realizing that the highest mask is `11100000` but you can just test the lowest bit of the mask. When mask is even, `f(input, mask) == f((input&mask)/2, mask/2)`. The highest *odd* mask is only `11000001` or 191. This reduces your LUT further, to `[192][192]`.

A more space-efficient algorithm splits `input` and `mask` into 2 nibbles (4 bits). You now have a very simple `LUT[16][16]` in which you look up the high and low parts:

```
int himask = mask >> 4, lomask = mask & 0xF;
int hiinp = input >> 4, loinp = input & 0xF;
unsigned char hiout = LUT[himask][hiinp];
unsigned char loout = LUT[lomask][loinp];
return hiout << bitsIn[lomask] | loout;
```

This shows that you need another table, `char bitsIn[15]`.

Taking the example :

```
mask  0010 1100b 
input 1010 0101b

himask = 0010
hiinp  = 1010
hiout  = 0001
lomask = 1100
loinp  = 0101
loout  = 0001
bitsIn[lowmask 1100] = 2
return (0001 << 2) | (0001)
```

Note that this generalizes fairly easily to more than 8 bits:

```
int bitsSoFar = 0;
int retval = 0;
while(mask) { // Until we've looked up all bits.
   int mask4 = mask & 0xF;
   int input4 = input & 0xF;
   retval |= LUT[mask4][input4] << bitsSoFar;
   bitsSoFar += bitsIn[mask4];
   mask >>= 4;
   input >>= 4;
}
```

Since this LUT only hold nibbles, you could reduce it to 16*16/2 bytes, but I suspect that's not worth the effort.

Comment: Good point, maybe I should edit the "can't avoid O(n)" out of my answer, since this doesn't consider the domain specific limitations given.

Comment: @grek40: Well, my second solution is O(n) in the number of nibbles, and with O(4) bits per nibble ;) that technically is the same. And all problems are O(1) given a sufficiently large LUT, so the first answer isn't that surprising either.

Answer (score 1):

I see it like this:

```
mask  00101100b 
input 10100101b
---------------
&     ??1?01??b
>>         101b
             5
```

I would create a bit weight table for each set bit in mask by scan bits from LSB and add weights `1,2,4,8,16...` for set bits and leave zero for the rest so:

```
      MSB           LSB
--------------------------
mask   0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 bin
--------------------------
weight 0 0 4 0 2 1 0 0 dec (A)
input  1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 bin (B)
--------------------------
(A.B) 0*1+0*0+4*1+0*0+2*0+1*1+0*0+0*1 // this is dot product ...
              4     +     1 
--------------------------
                     5 dec                 
--------------------------
```

Sorry I do not code in Python at all so no code ... I still think using integral types for this directly would be better but that is probably just my low level C++ thinking ...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my question. You method is one option, but it seems to be still of O(n) not O(m), as I have to do a multiplication for n=8 times before summation (7 additions). Maybe O(m) is just impossible for my problem.

Comment: @WanxinGao for low bit-counts is `O(1)` possible if you got fixed mask(s) just create table for each number and then use that only ... also the dot product only multiplies by `0` and `1` which is reduced to no or single addition only but still it is `O(n)`

Comment: "No or single addition" is a branch, that's probably worse than a multiplication. (Especially since the multiplication with a power of 2 really is just a bitshift). The problem is that you have a lot of branches, to extract all those individual bits for multiplication.